# Z3 Model: Can I instantiate by providing model as input?

Tags: z3

I am looking way by which I can instantiate Z3 context with Model as input. Instead of feeding my 100+ assertions every time I create context, can I export Model and then import?

Comment: Not clear at all what you are asking. Do you want to "save" the state of z3 so you can restart? Or do you want to put in new assertions after the first call according to the model? A more detailed example of what you are trying to do can elicit better answers!

Comment: Yes, in other words, save the state, so that I can restart in another session.

Comment: I don't think this is possible currently. But since this is an extremely specific z3 question you should really ask at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues so the developers of Z3 can chime in.